# custom fields in registration form in freemember module

Tags: freemember

In Freemember module, Can we add  Date of Birth and others field or calender in registration form with required field validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it yourself by simply adding a date picker to the field. However, it won't have any validation.

If you want a more powerful solution, I suggest checking out Zoo Visitor or one of the other member management modules which allow you to use regular custom fields with your members.